# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when loading images via Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

When I load an ArrayList of images into a GridView in a tablet(Nexus7) via Picasso,

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(movie.getMovieImageUrl()).into(imageViewPosterImage);
```

my app crashes with errors below. However, my app runs well on my phone (LG G2). 
I seriously suspect it is caused by consumption of memories of loading images. Although loaded via jar Picasso, images are much larger in a tablet than a phone. 
 How should I fix this bug up?

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1196 byte allocation with 13527808 free bytes and 12MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 131072 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 65536 bytes)
                at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                at nanodegree.udacity.leon.udacitypopularmovies.helper.DatabaseHelper.getAllMovieInfo(DatabaseHelper.java:156)
                at nanodegree.udacity.leon.udacitypopularmovies.display.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

It turns out not to be the loading problem, but the problem of fetching data from SQLiteDatabase.

```
public ArrayList<MovieInfoModel> getAllMovieInfo() {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "getAllMovieInfo() executed.");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<MovieInfoModel> allMovieInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    String getAllMovieInfoQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + STORED_TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getAllMovieInfoQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MovieInfoModel movieInfo = new MovieInfoModel();
        movieInfo.setMovieId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_ID)));
        movieInfo.setMovieOriginalTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_ORIGINAL_TITLE)));
        movieInfo.setMoviePlotSynopsis(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_PLOT_SYNOPSIS)));
        movieInfo.setMovieUserRating(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_USER_RATING)));
        movieInfo.setMovieReleaseDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE)));
        ArrayList<String> movieTrailerUrlArrayList = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_TRAILER_URL_JSON_STRING)), new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
        }.getType());
        movieInfo.setMovieTrailerUrlArrayList(movieTrailerUrlArrayList);
        ArrayList<MovieReviewModel> movieReviewArrayList = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_REVIEW_JSON_STRING)), new TypeToken<ArrayList<MovieReviewModel>>() {
        }.getType());

        movieInfo.setMovieReviewArrayList(movieReviewArrayList);
        allMovieInfoArrayList.add(movieInfo);
    }
    return allMovieInfoArrayList;
}
```

The error line is

```
ArrayList<MovieReviewModel> movieReviewArrayList = gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_REVIEW_JSON_STRING)), new TypeToken<ArrayList<MovieReviewModel>>() {
        }.getType());
```

It might be caused by `movieReviewArrayList` that is too large. `movieReviewArrayList` is an ArrayList of MovieReviewModel(a custom object), previously stored as JSON string turned by `GSON.jar`, and later when needed turned as `ArrayList<MovieInfoModel>` (via `GSON.jar`). How should store such a large file? 
In case one might need, I will post my `MovieReviewModel` class:

```
public class MovieReviewModel implements Parcelable {

private String reviewAuthor;
private String reviewContent;
private String reviewUrl;

constructors
setters
getters
Parcelable implementations
}
```

Comment: try `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(movie.getMovieImageUrl()).resize(1000, 1000).fit().into(imageViewPosterImage);`

Comment: It sounds like the images are too large to process

Comment: Thanks for both replies. Even if I `resize(100, 100)`, the same error (with exact number of bytes of memory needed) still occurs. It is not because of image loading, sorry for my wrong hint.

Comment: Do you really need all column? Can't you select a list of columns instead of select *

Comment: That is a good point. I can fetch data separately. But is this the best solution? I still tend to fetch the `ArrayList<MovieInfoModel>`. Is this the solution for extremely large files?

Comment: Actually reviews part is not that important. But the essence of the problem needs attention: how to store and retrieve large data/files from SQLiteDatabase?

Answer (score 3):

Having the same issue, for me

```
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
```

worked, e.g.

```
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(backdropURL).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).centerCrop().fit().into(backdropView);
```